# How to delete subpath in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, path, subdirectory

How can I edit path which i get from command line arguments and delete last subdirectory?

e.g. I run my batch file with argument: 
C:\Users\Aga\Desktop\something

and I want to use only 
"C:\Users\Aga\Desktop" 
part in my batch file.

Comment: Append `\..` to the path to point to the directory one level up (that is, the parent)... To resolve it (cosmetically), use `for %%P in ("C:\Users\Aga\Desktop\something\..") do echo %%~fP`...

Comment: Look also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070252/batch-file-going-back-two-steps-in-a-directory-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this as the very first line of your batch file:

```dos
@If Not "%~dp1"=="" @(Set "Parent=%~dp1"&Call Set "Parent=%%Parent:~,-1%%")
```

Then use **%Parent%** throughout your script as necessary, *(%Parent% will be the next directory up the tree if the input was a directory or the container folder if the input was a file)*.